# Как в JS реализовать в калькуляторе функцию вызова сообщения при делении на ноль

Tags: javascript, html

```js
// переменная, в которой хранится выбранное математическое действие
var op;
var reset = document.getElementById('C');
var memory = document.getElementById('M');
// функция расчёта
function func() {
  // переменная для результата
  var result;



  // получаем первое и второе число
  var num1 = Number(document.getElementById("num1").value);
  var num2 = Number(document.getElementById("num2").value);
  // смотрим, что было в переменной с действием, и действуем исходя из этого
  switch (op) {
    case '+':
      result = num1 + num2;
      break;
    case '-':
      result = num1 - num2;
      break;
    case '*':
      result = num1 * num2;
      break;
    case '/':
      result = num1 / num2;
      break;
    case 'xY':
      result = (Math.pow(num1, num2));
      break;


  }
  // отправляем результат на страницу
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
  // document.getElementById("memory").innerHTML = result;

}

function handler() {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = '';
  document.getElementById("memory").innerHTML = ' ';
  document.getElementById("num2").value = ' ';
  document.getElementById("num1").value = ' ';
}

reset.addEventListener("click", handler);

function handler2() {


  document.getElementById("memory").innerHTML = +
    (document.getElementById("result").innerHTML) + +
    (document.getElementById("memory").innerHTML);




}
memory.addEventListener("click", handler2);
```

```css
  #operator_btns {
  display: inline;
}

#num2 {
  display: block;
```

```html
<!-- поле ввода первого числа -->
<input id="num1" />

<!-- блок с кнопками -->
<div id="operator_btns">
  <button id="plus" onclick="op='+'">+</button>
  <button id="minus" onclick="op='-'">-</button>
  <button id="times" onclick="op='*'">*</button>
  <button id="divide" onclick="op='/'">/</button>
  <button id="xY" onclick="op='xY'">x^y</button>
  <button id="M" onclick="op='M'">M</button>

</div>
<button id="C">C</button>
<!-- поле ввода второго числа -->
<input id="num2" />
<br>

<!-- кнопка для расчётов -->
<button style="display:block" onclick="func()">Посчитать</button>

<!-- здесь будет результат -->
Результат
<p id="result"></p>
<!-- здесь будет память -->
Память
<p id="memory"></p>
```

Comment: `if (!num2) { alert('divide by zero') }` - ну и вставьте это в вашем кейсе

Comment: @SwaD лучше яано писать `if (+num2 === 0)` ... потому что `!num`  может означать что в num2 и пустая строка например, что явно не 0 ))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский `num2` по коду и так преобразуется к числу функцией `Number`. В общем и целом этого достаточно, что бы защититься от деления на **0**. Если прям проверять `+num2 === 0` то пропускается `NaN`. Конечно в вопросе четко указано по **0**, однако `NaN` тоже пропускать не стоит.

Comment: @SwaD Я не знаметил Number)) Но в целом да, может быть NaN, поэтому проверять на ноль нужно в данном случае явно, т.к. мы ожидаем конкретного явного поведения..... вот если было бы так, что выкиндывалось обобщённое сообщение "вы ввели не число", тогда можно было и !num делать или try/catch и пр.